# Specify gems specific for Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Is there a way to specify gems that are only installed when deploying to Heroku?  I want to be able to have two production environments, one that is on Heroku and on that is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a `:heroku` environment *(or any other string)* separate from `:production` for a heroku application. From **[the documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments)**:

```
heroku config:set RACK_ENV=heroku RAILS_ENV=heroku
```

Create your `config/environments/heroku.rb` for this environment, just like any other. Now you can specify a `:heroku` group in your `Gemfile` too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use groups in your Gemfile, like so:

```
group :heroku do
  gem 'something_that_should_only_be_installed_on_heroku'
end
```

Then, locally, install your Gemfiles with:

```
$ bundle install --without heroku
```